# How to trigger @valid automatically using Spring Boot in a GET Endpoint? Only works if @RequestBody is present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a couple of Endpoints, where I am using **@Valid** annotation and it works great.
However, I have an Endpoint (GET) ,where I send a couple of params and I map those params into a POJO:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endPoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Response> methodName(@Valid MyForm form)  {
```

The validation is never triggered, it seems it only works automatically if I use @RequestBody,and of course this is not the case.
I don't want to pass a list of parameters in the method, and add the validation in the same method, I want to do it this way.
The only solution I found ,it s to trigger the validator automatically and it works:

```
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyForm>> constraintViolation = validator.validate(form);
    if (!constraintViolation.isEmpty()) {
        throw new ConstraintViolationException(constraintViolation);
    }
```

Do yo know some more automatic way? I would like all endpoints validate fields in the same way.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `@ModelAttribute`.

Comment: Tried and not working :
   @RequestMapping(value = "/endPoint", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Response> methodName(@Valid @ModelAttribute MyForm form) ----------       
**The url calling that methods is :**

localhost/api/endpoint?token=0c0ac223-db8b-4061-8879-ff742a5f1795&Other_value&etc.....
Thanks

Comment: Then there must be something in your code that prevents this. That being said I thus doubt that what you shown here is the full picture of your controller.

Comment: Yes,it s the full full picture,.Indeed,i cant find any example on the internet using @Valid in a GET Endpoint.
What i found ,it s that Valid annotation it s triggered when using ResponseBody only.

Comment: That is wrong it works with model objects as well. Hence the fact that I doubt that this is the full picture. You only posted the method, not the controller, nor any other things. If some proxying is going on, annotations aren't inherited. So there must be something that permits this from working.

Comment: I will create an isolated project later, just a basic Spring controller with just 1 method to make a Proof of concept .I could share the link later . Thanks for your time

Comment: You were right. I was not showing the full picture. I have a RestExceptionHandler ,but the thing ,it s ,if the request it s a POST request and the validation fails, i have a ConstraintViolationException ,but but the GET request fails (the params in the URL) i need to handle BindException . So that was the problem, Overriding handleBindException from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler ,fixed the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry,the Post request throw a MethodArgumentNotValidException not a ConstraintViolation.